# Enormous green disk

Tags: google-docs, firefox

When I open a Google Docs document *anonymously* from my desktop computer (Windows 7 + Firefox esr 52), I always get this enormous green disk at the bottom right:

[image: Big green disk]
Clicking on it has no effect, except for the smaller white "Explore" button inside. Clicking on that white "Explorer" button opens the pivot table tool.

**How can I get rid of that disk so that it won't reappear in the future when I browse Google Docs anonymously?**

I guess it has something to do with the "Explorer" feature, but whoever thought it would be a good idea to make it take a sixth of my total screen space must have been high at the time.

[Edits]:

By "anonymously", I mean "not logged into my Google account", not "using the Private Browsing feature of Firefox".

Rubén's answer implies that it could be done by upgrading Firefox. So I should add that *I don't want to upgrade Firefox*. Maybe something about cookies keeping my preferences while browsing Google Docs without being logged in Google?

Comment: I think that the part about how to keep the "cookies keeping user preferences in anonymous mode" should be asked on [su] as it's something that depends on the SO/web browser rather than on the web application.

Comment: No, I mean "anonymous Google Docs mode" , not "Private Browsing" in Firefox. Sorry, wasn't clear. Damn, I'm bad at this. Edited accordingly, again.

Comment: (: I don't think that Google Docs and any other G Suite app (Forms, Sheets, Slides) use cookies to handle anonymous user preferences, actually I think that there isn't any preference for anonymous users, but there should be some kind of user tracking like the number of visits and the session duration. I have no idea if the Explorer button highlighting feature is related to that kind of information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very likely that the problem occurs due to a missing feature/incompatibility of Firefox esr 52.

From [System requirements and browsers](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2375082?hl=en) (emphasis mine)

> Google Drive, Docs, Sheets, Slides, and Forms work **with the 2 most recent versions** of the following browsers (unless specified otherwise).

Comment: It may very well be true, but I don't see how I can test your hypothesis without upgrading Firefox, which I don't want to do. I guess I'll cross my fingers and hope someone knows of a way without upgrading. I'll edit accordingly

Comment: You could create a new Windows user on your PC and install the last version for that user.

Comment: Ok. I'll try that for the sake of testing your hypothesis. That still leaves the question open (if you include my edit).